# Iterate througn [Java.lang.double in JS

Tags: postgis, leaflet, javascript, java

I have a Leaflet app with PostGIS and Geoserver at the server side. Some columns in PostGIS tables are of type  `Double[]` and contain arrays of double values. I need to get these arrays into my app and iterate through them. However, the arrays appear to come as `[Java.lang.double` objects which I can not handle.

```
my_layer.on('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.layer.feature.properties.fl_total);
});
```

This code returns `[Ljava.lang.Double;@4167b06f`. If I try to loop through it, js treats it as a string. How would I read these data?

Comment: What's the output from GeoServer? Is this from a WFS service, or something else? Are you using JSON as the transport protocol between GeoServer and Leaflet?

Comment: Thank you, I missed it. It is WFS. I use L.WFST to get my data into Leaflet.

Comment: can you add what the response of `DescribeFeatureType` is